# Path traversal filter bypass techniques?

Tags: path-injection

I have a Linux-based embedded system with web-interface for management purposes. According to one [security paper](http://tinyurl.com/p36wflx), this web-server has rudimentary filter against directory traversal attacks in URL parameters. So in order to bypass the "../" filter, an URL with special strings needs to be used. What are the common path traversal filter bypass techniques?

Comment: This is quite broad. Bypass techniques vary greatly depending on the blacklist that is used, the backend application environment (Windows, Linux-based, ASP.NET, Ruby, Perl, etc.). ..\ can be used, `..//..//` can be used, various encodings `%252e%252e%252f` is an example, and other techniques.

Comment: It would be helpful if you mentioned what linux system, what web application/server, and what 'security paper' you are asking about.

Comment: It is a VoIP phone based on Linux. However, while I analyzed the firmware image with hex editor, checked the phone boot log messages and used `nmap` service and OS detection scans, I got fairly little information. All I can say is that phone firmware is based on Linux 2.6 for MIPS, uses /proc file-system, uses JFFS2 file-system and web-server type is unknown. Even debugging log provides fairly little information regarding web server. All it says is that `PHN: WEBSV: init http_https, protected 0`. Security paper can be seen [here](http://tinyurl.com/p36wflx).

Comment: I recommend editing your question and adding the additional data including the link to the vulnerability report.

Comment: So you are looking to test whether your firmware has a fix for a specific vulnerability? Do you have access to a known vulnerable version of the firmware? I'd recommend testing there until you find the problem and then testing on the patched firmware.

Comment: @Martin "analyzed the firmware image with hex editor" A hex editor? That... sounds laborious. Did you try running `strings`, first? Or did you get data off the phone with a logic analyzer?

Comment: @NeilSmithline I added link to vulnerability report. I do have the Snom phone with vulnerable version of the firmware installed, but so far I have not been able to successfully execute the path traversal attack. @Parthian Shot I did try with `strings` as well, but finally according to `binwalk` utility it turned out that firmware image is encrypted.

Answer (score 16):

There are various encodings you can try to enable you to bypass a filter:

- Try `/` and `\` at the start of the folder name to try and reach the root directory.
- Try `%2f` and `%5c` (percent encoded versions of the above).
- Try using 16-bit Unicode encoding (`.` = `%u002e`, `/` = `%u2215`, `\` = `%u2216`).
- Try double URL encoding (`.` = `%252e`, `/` = `%252f`, `\` = `%255c`).
- Try overlong UTF-8 Unicode encoding (`.` can be `%c0%2e`, `%e0%40%ae`, `%c0ae`, `/` can be `%c0%af`, `%e0%80%af`, `%c0%2f`, etc, `\` can be `%c0%5c`, `%c0%80%5c`).

If you get a different response trying one of the above then you have managed to change either the execution path or the file system path that is being accessed. This may indicate that the particular sequence used may be worthy of additional investigation.

Comment: Thanks for all those encodings! Now I should use those instead of expected user input? I mean for example instead of `192.168.1.87/line_features.htm?l=1` I need to use `192.168.1.87/line_features.htm?l=%c0ae%c0ae%c0%2f%c0ae%c0ae%c0%2f%c0ae%c0ae%c0%2f%c0ae%c0ae%c0%2fetc/passwd` and other similar combinations?

Comment: Without knowing which server or the vulnerability this is hard to answer. Look especially for parameters that take a file parameter, and test as you described.

Comment: All the information I have is [here](http://tinyurl.com/p36wflx). As much as I analyzed the phone (bootup) log files and did nmap service detection scans, then it does not seem to have some well-known web server. I also used the `dotdotpwn` tool(for example `dotdotpwn.pl -m http-url -u http://192.168.1.87/line_features.htm?l=TRAVERSAL -f /etc/passwd%00 -o unix -x 80 -U user -P passwd -k "user"`) in order to generate URL's automatically, but I feel like I'm just randomly trying.

Comment: I would guess that in the reference `The string [removed] at the end is necessary` that `[removed]` could be the null byte (%00). Bear in mind this is guess work and it is impossible to hack by proxy in such a way.

Comment: I see. I tested with `%00` at the end when I used `dotdotpwn.pl -m http-url -u http://192.168.1.87 /line_features.htm?l=TRAVERSAL -f /etc/passwd%00 -o unix -x 80 -k "root"`. This will send GET requests like `GET /line_features.htm?l=%2e.%c1%af%2e.%c1%afetc%c1%afpasswd%00 HTTP/1.1` to phone.

Answer (score 4):

For web app security, many common hacks are documented in the associated OWASP test guides and attack pages. OWASP provides a path traversal [attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) and [testing guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Path_Traversal_(OWASP-AZ-001)).

The general concept is to use characters that can fool the path traversal code. Things like embedded nulls, unicode notation, and such can sometimes bypass the path traversal filter.

Note that a strong implementation will not be susceptible to any of these. It will use a character white-list and other measures that will prevent any of these tricks from succeeding.

Comment: Thanks! As I understand, first step is to enumerate all the parts of web-application which accept content from the user. For example `http://192.168.1.87/line_login.htm?l=1` or `http://192.168.1.87/index.htm?dialeddel=clear`? I guess usually those are found by crawling the web-application and searching for `?`(query string) in URLs?

Comment: That's a start but far from the entire process. Paths can be passed as POST data that won't show up in query parameters. Also, you could have an URL like `http://example.com/upload.jsp/c:/foo/bar` where the `c:/foo/bar` is a filename. It is best if you are intimate with the functionality of the app you are testing to identify the path locations.